# inverse of a partial derivative for 3 function with 2 variable

Tags: calculus

I have 3 functions of 2 variables,
$$M_1 = M_0 sin(\theta)\cdot cos(\phi)$$
$$M_2 = M_0 sin(\theta)\cdot sin(\phi)$$
$$M_3 = M_0 cos(\theta)$$

I need to calculate: 
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial M_1}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial M_1},
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial M_2}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial M_2},
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial M_3}, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial M_3}$$

Had it been two functions of 2 variables, then I could calculate the matrix of \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial M_1} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial M_1}\\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial M_2} & \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial M_2}
\end{pmatrix} and then take the inverse matrix.
For this situation, what can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please learn about the usage of MathJax notation (see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing symbols on your posts! In its current form, it is quite hard to read. I've done some edits for you this time

Comment: If you take $M_0$ as variable, this is simply the well-known transformation from spherical to rectangular coordinates. You could look up or compute the inverse transformation, or, assume temporarily that $M_0$ **is** an independent variable and invert the resulting Jacobian matrix. Yet another possibility is to apply implicit differentiation to your three equations and then solve the resulting system.